# Forgot to bring identity card

Tags: writing, email

Can someone help me out in following scenario,

> "I placed my Identity card in home , so i got an temporary card from
>   reception"

How do i inform this to my manager through mail?
 Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you want to tell your manager that you only have a temporary card (from the reception desk)?

Comment: "I forgot my ID. I'm using a temporary card today that I got from reception."

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yes

Comment: Jolenealaska's example is good. I might rephrase your sentence as "I left my I.D. Card at home. I only have a temporary card now." (I'm guessing that you want to tell your manager that you are unable to do something at the moment, and might need his or her help.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. thank u . i dont need his help , i just wanted to inform him and apoligize

Comment: If that is the case, I would say that Jolenealaska's is better than mine. (As a side note, you can use either "I forgot (to bring) my I.D. Card" or "I left my I.D. Card at home".)

Comment: @Dam should i use something like "apologise for my activity?"?

Comment: Though something like "My apologies." is possible, I personally would use something like "I'm really sorry." or "I'm really sorry that it happened." or "I'm really sorry for my mistake." The choice is really up to you.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Can u suggest me a suitable subject for this mail? and this is how i formed my sentence `I forgot to bring my ID card and I'm using a temporary card today that I got from reception. I'm really sorry that it happened.`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about learning the English language. Try [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to suggest keeping the mail simple, and express your thoughts as direct as possible. The trick of an apology letter is not writing skill, but it's about honesty and being able to recognize your own mistakes. For example,

> *Subject:* I'm sorry I forgot my ID card
>
> I forgot to bring my ID card today. I'm using a temporary card I got from the reception (desk). I'm really sorry that it happened. (I'll do my best to not to let it happen again.)
>
> Your sincerely,
> San Krish

NOTE: You can choose to include or not include the parts in the parentheses. For one thing, I'm not sure if your reception can be called the reception desk. Also, if you think *"I'll do my best to not to let it happen again,"* is a little too much, you can omit it.